# how to create Flash movies from PDF documents

Tags: flash, pdf2swf

I'm looking for an help to implement flash paper in my web site( sample .net web program). 
Requirement is any .doc and PDF file should automatically convert into flash paper at the time of display.

I would appreciate if I get help on how to create Flash movies from PDF documents.

Sample site url http://pdfmenot.com/

Looking for  practical implementation of dynamic conversion

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [SWF Tools](http://www.swftools.org/).  One of the tools included is PDF2SWF, which I think will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for quick update.

I am looking for sample .net program to create dynamic flashpaper.
I got a sample code from net but I don’t know how to implement.

Sample site url http://pdfmenot.com/ 

(http://www.labnol.org/internet/tools/convert-pdf-flash-pdfmenote-online-pdf-to-swf-converter/2280/)

Sampel code.
IFlashPaperConnect oFlashPaper = new
LibFlashPaperConnectServer2.CoFlashPaperConnectSer verClass();
oFlashPaper.BeginConversion( sInputFilename, sOutputFilename, 0, 0, 0
);
oFlashPaper.EndConversion();


I am looking for a practical implementation of this .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a single procedure to do this but you could use ImageMagick to convert the PDF to a series of images. Then [Ming Sharp](http://ming-sharp.sourceforge.net/) could be used to create the SWFs.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe makes a product that does this called [FlashPaper](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashpaper/). Costs money, but I hear it can be used in batch on a server.

Answer (score 0):

PDF2SWF Tool. It works for me